# Insert and update SQL server from Datagrid

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently displaying data from SQL server in a `DataGrid` using `C#`. I want to expand on this and be able to insert and update the SQL server straight from the app that contains the `DataGrid`. I am looking for advice or tutorials on how to do this. Let me know if you need to see my code. Thanks.

Comment: what I am thinking is, when a line in the datagrid is clicked, a new window opens where that line can be updated. And a button that will open a new window where a new item can be inserted.

Comment: how are you currently populating your datagrid, with a stored procedure, plain text SQL, LINQ, etc?

Comment: using a SQLDataSource? Entity Data Model? Other....? For plenty of tutorials you can check out the msdn data developer area http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc300162

Comment: This should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following links. Hope to solve the issues.

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/InsertingWithGridView.aspx)

[C Sharp Dot Net Freak](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/gridview-sqldatasource-insert-edit.html)